# How to convert array object into a particular format

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

Data which I am getting from backend is in array object format how can I convert that a particular data format for example:

```js
data = [
  { name: value, age: value, phoneNumber: value, email: value },
  { name: value, age: value, phoneNumber: value, email: value },
  { name: value, age: value, phoneNumber: value, email: value },
]
```

I want that data into this format for example:

```js
data = {
  person: [
    { name: value, email: value },
    { name: value, email: value },
    { name: value, email: value },
  ],
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this with `map`

```
data = {
  person: data.map(({ name, email }) => ({ email, name })),
}
```